# Write a program that first asks the user how many email addresses they will be entering, and then has the user enter those addresses

Tags: python

Q. At a certain school, student email addresses end with @student.college.edu, while professor email addresses end with @prof.college.edu. Write a program that first asks the user how many email addresses they will be entering, and then has the user enter those addresses. After all the email addresses are entered, the program should print out a message indicating either that all the addresses are student addresses or that there were some professor addresses entered.

So far I've come up with this code:

```
nStudents=0
nProfs=0
a=int(input('please enter no. of emails'))

for i in range(a):
    b=input('enter email')
    if b[-18:-1]=='@student.college.edu':
        nStudents=nStudents+1
    elif b[-15:-1]=='@prof.college.edu':
        nProfs=nProfs+1
print('number of students=',nStudents,'number of professors=',nProfs)
```

But the output is continuously 0 professors and 0 students. I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Hello, you can try like this: `if '@student.college.edu' in b: nStudents=nStudents+1` and for the next line too.

Comment: `b[-18:-1]` is omitting the last character. How about `if b.endswith(...)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indexing is not correct.

```
if b[-20:]=='@student.college.edu':
    ...
elif b[-17:]=='@prof.college.edu':
```

I could have suggested the usage of "endswith", and I DO encourage you to check it, but I find it better to tell you WHY what you wrote didn't work. I think that this more  constructive feedback. Happy coding. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

How about splitting the string by '@'s?

```py
nStudents = 0
nProfs = 0
a=int(input('please enter no. of emails: '))

for i in range(a):
    b=input('enter email: ')
    if b.split('@')[1] == 'student.college.edu':
        nStudents += 1
    elif b.split('@')[1] == 'prof.college.edu':
        nProfs += 1
print('number of students=',nStudents,'number of professors=',nProfs)
```

Or using `endswith`:

```py
nStudents = 0
nProfs = 0
a=int(input('please enter no. of emails: '))

for i in range(a):
    b=input('enter email: ')
    if b.endswith('@student.college.edu'):
        nStudents += 1
    elif b.endswith('@prof.college.edu'):
        nProfs += 1
print('number of students=',nStudents,'number of professors=',nProfs)
```

Comment: The most robust solution of the two answers. +1 because I didn't know of "endswith"